# PHP не создает базу SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite3

Установлен PHP 7.1, echo phpinfo() сообщает о подключенном драйвере SQLite. Сервер IIS. Однако выполнение скрипта:

```
<?php
$database = new SQLiteDatabase('test.db');
```

не производится, база не создается. Также не подключается к уже существующей. 
Результат:

> Сайт localhost пока не может обработать этот запрос. HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 1):

Класс с именем `SQLiteDatabase` упомянут в старом расширении [`sqlite`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php), которое было удалено из ядра уже 6 лет назад, в релизе 5.4.0. Возможно ли собрать его из PECL для php 7.1 - сильно сомневаюсь.

Вам нужно использовать актуальное расширение [`sqlite3`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php). Если разработка ваша - то обновляйте связанный код. Если не ваша - скорей всего это приложение вы вообще не заставите работать с таким разрывом в версиях. Ищите обновления либо альтернативы.

Но в любом случае уточняйте настоящую ошибку в логах.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.sqlite.php#sqlite.class.sqlitedatabase

Comment: Забавно, куда же его из reference выбросили.

Comment: Папка с логами пуста. В консоле следующее сообщение: *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)*

Comment: Это отвечает web-сервер, поскольку скрипт выдал ошибку. Надо выяснить, что за ошибка. В php.ini включите отображение всех ошибок

Comment: Оба класса (SQLite3 и SQLiteDatabase) не найдены. *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.php on line 2*. В серверной папке ext, на которую ссылается phpinfo() есть php_sqlite3.dll.

Comment: dll вкладывают, но включать виндовые пользователи всё равно должны явно в конфиге. Директивы extension в php.ini

Comment: После добавления extension удалось открыть конструктором SQLite3 существующую базу, созданную командной строкой. Уже успех, спасибо. Но все же хочется узнать, почему ни один из двух конструкторов не создает объекты и как это исправить.

Comment: Разобрался. Действительно, SQLiteDatabase больше не поддерживается (https://serverfault.com/questions/117610/why-class-sqlitedatabase-is-not-found-in-var-www-php). А конструктор SQLite3 не имел права записи, изменил директорию локалхоста, теперь создает. Всем спасибо, очень помогли.